# ELI5 Why do we drop highly correlated features?

Tags: correlation, feature-selection

Let's say we have a classification task with two features, such that classes "can't" be separated because the Pearson correlation equals 1.

If we train decision tree on that, will both of those features in that case have the same info gain? Even if the datapoints lie on a line y=a*x such that a =/= 1.

I might see why it might be problem for classification tasks to have highly correlated features (no separation?), but in case of a regression? Why is it a problem?

If one could explain for example on this case:

Example: Pointing to a fancy chart, Roger shows how temperatures have been rising over the past few centuries, whilst at the same time the numbers of pirates have been decreasing; thus pirates cool the world and global warming is a hoax.

Comment: "ELI5" is "explain it like I'm five" (i.e. explain it in simple terms that a child would understand).

Comment: @Dave It's optional but yeah something easier to grasp would be imensely helpful!